# Want to create a menu for my Game Java eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Hi I currently made a game and just wish to add a simple menu for it, the are two buttons on the main menu was says English and the Other says French I have managed to get the English button working which takes me to my EnglishVersion.class but I cant seem to get my French button to work. can any one help please.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainMenu extends Activity {

Button English;
Button French;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
addListenerOnButton();

}


public void addListenerOnButton(){

final Context context = this;

English = (Button) findViewById(R.id.engbtn);
French = (Button) findViewById(R.id.frenbtn);
English.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()


{

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

Intent intent = new Intent(context, EnglishVersion.class);
startActivity(intent);

}



});
}
```

I have tried to do this and getting and im getting an error

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainMenu extends Activity {

    Button English;
    Button French;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
        English.setOnClickListener(mButtonClickListener);
        French.setOnClickListener(mButtonClickListener);
    }

    private View.OnClickListener mButtonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (view.getId()==R.id.engbtn) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, EnglishVersion.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    } else if (view.getId()==R.id.frenbtn) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, FrenchVersion.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                }
            }

            }
```

Comment: You don't appear to have wired up a click listener to your `French` button which is likely why it doesn't work whereas you do add a click listener for your `English` button

Comment: Putting all your class code in your questions reduces the readability of your question and a lot of people may just give up and not read/answer the question entirely. Try adding short but informative snippets of code in your question

Answer (score 0):

add this:

```
French.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, FrenchVersion.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

By the way, it's not a good way to do the internationalization.

Try to read little about it here 
[Supporting Different Languages](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html)

You can just create various files strings-XX.XML in your res/ directory, where XX is given language symbol like FR or EN. It will even work with your default one. So if phone user has French defined as a language,  your application will take it as its.

Answer (score 0):

Either use the onClick property in XML like this (for both buttons);

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/engbtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClick"/>

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/frenbtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClick"/>
```

then populate the onClick method in the activity;

```
     public void onClick(View view) {
         if (view.getId()==R.id.engbtn) {
             //do something
         } else if (view.getId()==R.id.frenbtn) {
             //do something else
         }
     }
```

OR set the onClickListeners for both button like this;

```
English.setOnClickListener(mButtonClickListener);
French.setOnClickListener(mButtonClickListener);
```

and then define the shared click listener;

```
    private View.OnClickListener mButtonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (view.getId()==R.id.engbtn) {
               //do something
            } else if (view.getId()==R.id.frenbtn) {
               //do something else
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps!